# Changing transfer function of a plant

Tags: controller

When we design a controller we assume that there is a stable transfer function of a plant. But if we think an elevator, its transfer function will change because when people get on the elevator or get off the elevator its transfer function will be change. But we first design the controller for a stable transfer function of a plant so achieved design spesifications may not be assured such as overshoot, settling time steady state error. Thanks for answering

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: How can we control a dynamic plant? Do we need a adaptable controller if so how can we achieve it with root locus other than neural network? Or do we need a forced plant that it comply with a previously defined plant model? Thanks